# How to get and combine an element from multiple lists in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a function as shown below.

```
f1<-function(x)
{
  df1 <- rowSums(x)
  df2 <- colSums(x)
  return(list(Actuals = df1,Summary = df2))
}
```

I am calling that function by group as shown below.

```
out <- by( mtcars, INDICES = mtcars$gear, f1, simplify = TRUE )
```

Now I need to get only Summary from all the groups and combine them together in a dataframe.

I can do it with the below code.

```
summary <- do.call( rbind, sapply( out, function(x) x$Summary, simplify = FALSE ) )
summary <- cbind( Gear = as.integer( row.names(summary) ), summary )
```

But this process is very slow. I have thousands of groups in my original dataset and this approach is taking around 20 mins to do the same.

Could anyone provide a better approach with `data.table` or any other packages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends a bit on whether `rowSums` and `colSums` are just example functions, or actually what you want to do. Because `mtcars[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=gear]` in *data.table* will give a similar result.

Comment: ```f1``` function is just an example. I have very lengthy and complex function. But returning two data frames in a list format. now I need to combine an item from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Even with tens of thousands of groups, the reshaping operations in the current solution take just seconds. I suspect almost all the processing time is spent in the actual `f1` function.

Below is one way to use `data.table` to accomplish (essentially) the same thing. It runs about twice as fast.

*Example* `f1` function (modified based on the comment "`f1` function is just an example. I have very lengthy and complex function. But returning two data frames in a list format."):

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  df1 <- as.data.frame(t(rowSums(x)))
  df2 <- as.data.frame(t(colSums(x)))
  return(list(Actuals = df1, Summary = df2))
}
```

`f1` modified to return nested lists.

```
f2 <- function(x) {
  df1 <- as.data.frame(t(rowSums(x)))
  df2 <- as.data.frame(t(colSums(x)))
  return(list(Actuals = list(df1), Summary = list(df2)))
}
```

Make a much bigger dataset for illustration.

```
library(data.table)
bigcars <- setDT(copy(mtcars))
bigcars <- rbindlist(lapply(1:1e4, function(i) copy(bigcars[,gear := gear + 3L])))
```

Original solution:

```
system.time({
  out <- by(bigcars, INDICES = bigcars$gear, f1, simplify = TRUE)
  summary <- do.call(rbind, sapply(out, function(x) x$Summary, simplify = FALSE))
  summary <- cbind(Gear = as.integer(row.names(summary)), summary)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   11.82    0.15   11.99
```

`data.table` solution:

```
system.time({
  out2 <- setDT(copy(bigcars))[, f2(.SD), gear]
  summary2 <- rbindlist(out2$Summary)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    5.34    0.11    5.47
```

Note that the `[, f2(.SD), gear]` operation does not pass the grouping variable to `f2`, so `gear` does not appear in `summary2`. The operation may need to be modified depending on what the actual `f1` function is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, jblood94. It is giving me an error like ```argument is not a matrix```. In my output, I have multiple data types including Date, character, etc.

Comment: See the updated answer. I modified your example `f1` function based on your comment about it returning two `data.frames` in a list. Your example `f1` function was returning two vectors in a list.

Comment: Again, I don't suspect that streamlining the reshaping is going to make much of a difference. Here we see an improvement of ~6 seconds on a moderately sized `data.table`. There's not room to shave off minutes from your overall computation. I suspect `f1` is the culprit.